# Hibernate/JPA refresh whole collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a `Lazy load` `@OneToMany`

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private List<OrderItem> orderItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

After a long operation, I want to refresh the `orderItems` entities.

I have to loop over the childs and refresh like below:

```
for (OrderItem orderItem : order.getOrderItems()) {
   entityManager.refresh(orderItem);
}
```

I believe this is very not efficient, because it is trying to refresh the entity one by one, which mean it fires the SQL one by one.

I believe how hibernate works when we call proxy wrapper `getOrderItems`, it is just fire one SQL to select the records by the parent's foreign key. This is more efficient.

Am I able to refresh the whole list in this way?

Comment: Could you please explain why you need to refresh the entities? Why not refresh the parent entity, or cancel the transaction altogether? Is the long operation you're referring to wrapped in a transaction?

Comment: @crizzis refresh parent entity will refresh the child? I check the cascade type, there is no such option. Yes, long operation mean it is wrapped in a transaction.

Comment: `ALL = DETACH, MERGE, PERSIST, REFRESH, REMOVE`

Comment: @crizzis I see.. it is my mistake... i have overlooked it from here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/metamodel/binding/CascadeType.html

Comment: @crizzis so by refreshing the parent, hibernate should have refresh the collection at once right? instead of refresh the child entities one by one.

Comment: Yes. Of course, refreshing an entity overwrites changes made to it in a transaction. You have been warned

Comment: @GMsoF `so by refreshing the parent, hibernate should have refresh the collection at once right?`. yes it does refresh the collection but it will  not happen with a single SQL query. So for each item in the collection you would see a SQL query being fired and not at once(i.e., not with single query for entire collection).

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu I see, thanks for highlighting.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt if it is possible to tell entityManager to  refresh the entire collection with a single statement or a single SQL. I think it would really be nice if JPA provides such feature and say refresh by issuing a single SQL based on the parent ID.

EntitiManager.refresh() method expects us to pass a managed entity. So we can't pass a List<> directly to this method. So only other two options I see are:

1. Iterate the collection and call refresh on each entity.(as you did)
   OR
2. Call refresh on the parent object with CascadeType.REFRESH on child collection. Although this would still result in firing a DB query for each entity in the child collection.

Comment: Calling `refresh` will cause changes made to the entities within the list to be discarded. `merge` will result in quite the opposite. One should be really careful with side effects in the above scenario

Comment: @crizzis my mistake, I meant calling a refresh, not merge,  on the parent entity. Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use second level cache use named query to fetch the parent entity together with the child relation. This will be significantly more efficient compared to refreshin each member one by one.

The cool thing is that the named query will go around the first level cache.

If you use second level cache you need to evict the entity first.